# Show weight on each variant [ Shopify]

Tags: shopify, liquid

Hello I want to know how to show weight on each variant???

Right now i used this to call weight {{ variant.weight | weight_with_unit }}
but I have this result

[image]

and here's my whole code to show variants

```
              <div class="product-options__section d-flex flex-wrap" data-style="text" data-property="{% render 'product-get-options-strip-symbols' with value: option.name %} {{ variant. weight }}"{% if disable_auto_select %} data-disable-auto-select{% endif %}>
                        {%- for value in option.values -%}
                            {% include 'product-get-options-res-status' with option_index0: option_index0 %}
                            <div class="product-options__value product-options__value--text d-flex flex-center border cursor-pointer{% if disabled_value %} disabled{% elsif hidden_value %} disabled-hidden{% endif %}{% if active_value %} active{% endif %}"
                                 data-js-option-value
                                 data-value="{% render 'product-get-options-strip-symbols' with value: value %}"
                                 {{ trigger_attr }}
                                 data-scale="2"
                            >{{ value | replace: '<', '&lt;' | replace: '>', '&gt;' }}{{ variant.weight | weight_with_unit }}<span></span></div>
                        {%- endfor -%}
                    </div>
```

Comment: What if you display just `variant.weight`? Is it still 0? In that case, can you double check the weight is set in the variant?

Comment: yap still, and have values on my weight.

I tried this code current_variant.weight but it only shows the weight of the first variant

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're code is using the `product_option` instead of variants.

Product options are automatically created by shopify when you add variants.

For example if you have a T-shirt in 3 sizes and 2 colours, you have 6 variants but you have 3 size options and 2 colour options. But the option object doesn't have the properties of the variant.

As far as I know is not easy to go from option to variant. A suggestion that is easy for me, but not for you, is to rewrite the loop using the variants.

Not having the whole code, I can suggest you this solution which is far from being perfect, but it should work.

```
              <div class="product-options__section d-flex flex-wrap" data-style="text" data-property="{% render 'product-get-options-strip-symbols' with value: option.name %} {{ variant. weight }}"{% if disable_auto_select %} data-disable-auto-select{% endif %}>
                        {%- for value in option.values -%}
                            {% include 'product-get-options-res-status' with option_index0: option_index0 %}
{% for variant in product.variants %}
{% if variant.options contains value %} {% comment %} this might not work if you have multiple level of options %} {% endcomment %}
{% break %}
{% endfor %}
                            <div class="product-options__value product-options__value--text d-flex flex-center border cursor-pointer{% if disabled_value %} disabled{% elsif hidden_value %} disabled-hidden{% endif %}{% if active_value %} active{% endif %}"
                                 data-js-option-value
                                 data-value="{% render 'product-get-options-strip-symbols' with value: value %}"
                                 {{ trigger_attr }}
                                 data-scale="2"
                            >{{ value | replace: '<', '&lt;' | replace: '>', '&gt;' }}{{ variant.weight | weight_with_unit }}<span></span></div>
                        {%- endfor -%}
                    </div>
```